# How to open new browser window for popup?

Tags: javascript

Following Javscript can open popup:

```
window.open('http://www.google.com','mywindow','width=400,height=200');
```

If call it two times like:

```
window.open('http://www.google.com','mywindow1','width=400,height=200');
window.open('http://www.google.com','mywindow2','width=400,height=200');
```

The later will override previous only one popup. I want to two separated windows for popup at sametime with above code. even I set different reference name like mywindow1, mywindow2.

How to fix this problem?

More info:

The way I call js in code-behind is:

```
string js = "<script language=javascript> window.open("myurl1","_blank","DialogWidth=700;DialogHeight=750;left=30;top=30;");</script>";
Response.Write(sUrl);

js = "<script language=javascript> window.open("myurl2","_blank","DialogWidth=700;DialogHeight=750;left=30;top=30;");</script>";
Response.Write(sUrl);
```

It looks like later close the previous window.

Comment: Just wanted to say that I'd never go to a site with multiple popups at the same time...

Comment: please stop opening popup it's so '99 :) use modal popup instead, and you won't have any blocker problem.

Comment: @remi: *Shhhhh, don't tell* (Just kidding, there are some legitimate use cases for `window.open`. Three, I think.)

Comment: 1/ you have a viagra website. 2/ you have a porn website. 3 you have a poker website. In each case your website must be a scam, and you have to ask for credit card number (with no ssl).

Comment: I use popup for report. need to open more than one report at same time.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank','width=400,height=200');
window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank','width=400,height=200');
```

See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Correct; you don't need to set a name because `window.open()` returns the window object so you can access it directly.

Comment: I tried above solution and still only get one. I use Response.Write(jsstring) in code behind. I added the info in above post.

Answer (score 0):

[It shouldn't](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open), you should get a new window because the window names are different ("mywindow1" vs. "mywindow2"). Do you really need to name the windows? If not, try ["_blank"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.16) instead. If you're not putting the digits on the end, that's your problem — using the same window name reuses the window (by design).